# LinkedIn Developer App JavaScript API Domains Limits

Tags: linkedin-api

We host sites for multiple clients and want to allow them custom branded urls. This will require us to add entries for each of these new urls to the JavaScript API Domains section of our application. My question is, do we have a limit on the amount of domains we can allow for our application? If so, how many? We are going to need to allow 100s. I cannot find it exclusive stated in the developer documentation. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface limits you to 50 domains at the moment.  If you need more, you'd have to subdivide them out between different application ids.